# Async/Await not working when calling a web service

Tags: vb.net, web-services, asynchronous

For some reason,  I can't get the generated [Service Method Name]Async version of any method to compile in a web service I create in VB.NET.

I get the same format of error message, no matter whether I'm using the actual service I've created or even the default service with its HelloWorld and HelloWorldAsync methods.  So I'm obviously not doing something key that's required.

The format of the error message in the VS 2012 code window is [Service MethodName]Response cannot be converted to [Type that will be returned].  So in the case of the default HelloWorld method, this code snippet :
    Imports StackOverflowClient.TestServiceReference

Public Class Form1
    Dim SOClient As New TestWebServiceSoapClient

```
Private Async Sub SayHelloAsync()
    Label1.Text = Await SOClient.HelloWorldAsync()
End Sub
```

End Class

(Where StackOverflowClient is the name of the project,TestServiceReference is the Namespace assigned to the Service, and SOClient is the proxy class) will error out with the message:  HelloWorldResponse cannot be converted to String.  (In my real application, the message will be GetUserResponse cannot be converted to the User type I've created in the service.

I've also sometimes had an error message of "Expression does not produce a value" when trying to do this with classes from the service, eg:
    lblUser.Text = StaffInfoService.GetNextStaffMemberAsync()

I have the 'Allow generation of asynchronous operations' checkbox checked in the Service Reference Settings.

I can't see what I've missed.    I don't want to have to use the older Begin/Completed/Callback approach of pre VS2010 unless I absolutely have to.  Any pointers to using Async/Await for this task will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like `HelloWorldAsync` is returning a type of `Task<HelloWorldResponse>`. When you `Await` it, the task is "unwrapped" and the type of the value is then `HelloWorldResponse`. As the error message states, you can't convert this to a string. Perhaps you are looking for a particular property of that type?

Comment: Thanks Stephen. You're right, it is returning a type of HelloWorldResponse.   When you say "looking for a particular property of that type', do you mean the HelloWorldResponse type?  If so, that's where I'm stuck, as I don't see in Intellisense the actual type that I do want returned by the web method.  (In my actual project, a StaffMember type from the service.  I guess it's pulling that StaffMember type out of the Response is where I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes, I mean the `HelloWorldResponse` type. Are you saying that your server just returns a `StaffMember` type? If so, is it appropriately defined as a `[DataContract]`?

Comment: No, you were correct in thinking that it returns a Response type - in the actual project it's a GetNextStaffMemberResponse.  I can see in the Object Browser that this type has properties, such as Body, but I don't see how I can pull the StaffMember instance that the GetNextStaffMemberAsync is supposed to return.    When I use the synchronous GetNextStaffMember method of the server, that successfully returns an instance of StaffMember that I can use, but the Async version that is auto-generated returns the GetNextStaffMemberResponse.

Comment: Sounds like WCF is messing up or misconfigured somewhere. Try creating a minimal repro in a new WCF service.

Comment: I'm using the older ASP.NET web service.  Is that where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure. I have very little experience with XML-based web services.